# Slew Rate, Settling Time, Bandwidth, Rise Time - High Speed Transimpedance Amplifier Design

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm in the process of designing a Transimpedance amplifier for an analytical instrument. The sample waveform (hand-drawn) is attached in the attachments. The requirement is to amplify a pulse kind of signal whose maximum amplitude is around 700 nA and the width of the pulse is around 1 ns. So, I need a high-speed transimpedance amplifier.
My question is what are the opamp parameters that decide the speed of the amplifier. I need a concrete relationship between slew rate, settling time, rise time, bandwidth/gain-bandwidth. And particular to the signal which parameter is most important so that I can choose the right opamp for the design.
Regards
M Arivalagan
[image]

Comment: Good luck. If you google for one, please note the price. You are probably looking for an opamp with bandwidth in excess of 5 GHz.

Comment: You forgot to give what gain on the output you want, this will determine the slew rate and Gain Bandwidth Produce scaling lets say you have 100MHz GBP, and a gain of 100, well then you have a Bandwidth of 1MHz, as I am assuming you would like a rather large gain you may have to approach it with a cascaded amplifier to keep the bandwidth high enough at the cost of some added noise.

Comment: You may find this enlightening: https://www.electronicdesign.com/analog/whats-all-transimpedance-amplifier-stuff-anyhow-part-1

Comment: It is important to know the source impedance ( usually, the source capacitance) to design a trans impedance amplifier. More information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this: a common-base amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDu0iP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For more bandwidth, increase the Vce to reduce Cob; thus take +5v to +10v.